# Regression design, difference in differences

Tags: econometrics

I plan to look at the regional differences of a policy effect. I would like to use the difference in differences approach however I am not sure how to assign a control group. I have data for time periods before and after implementation for the same regions. However, the policy was a national approach to improve a particular issue the nation faces meaning the policy was non-excludable. Any advice ?

Comment: Without knowing more about your study, here are a couple if things that could work: 1) Split your regions along some meaningful dimension (e.g., income inequality) and incorporate that explicitly into the regression.  This will show how differences along that dimension are related to the policy impact. 2) If your data for each region is very dense around the time of the policy implementation, and each region is trending similarly before the policy, you could try a regression discontinuity approach. This would not need a control group, but would require a rapid policy impact.

Comment: There's no "control group" designed into the policy experiment. As a result, you'd need to find something that comes up as a natural experiment. It would be helpful to know the details of the policy.